# Converting raw input non-csv into a list of integers

Tags: python, csv

I searched the forums here on stack and other sites and didn't find what I need. I am pretty new to Python also, so let's keep that in mind. I'm using Python 2.7.3. What I am trying to do is make a list of prime numbers from raw input that doesn't have a comma.

```
   1000003   1000033   1000037   1000039   1000081   1000099

   1000117   1000121   1000133   1000151   1000159   1000171   1000183   1000187 

   1000193   1000199   1000211   1000213   1000231   1000249   1000253   1000273 

   1000289   1000291   1000303   1000313   1000333   1000357   1000367   1000381 

   1000393   1000397   1000403   1000409   1000423   1000427   1000429   1000453 

   1000457   1000507   1000537   1000541   1000547   1000577   1000579   1000589 

   1000609   1000619   1000621   1000639   1000651   1000667   1000669   1000679 

   1000691   1000697   1000721   1000723   1000763   1000777   1000793   1000829 

   1000847   1000849   1000859   1000861   1000889   1000907   1000919   1000921 

   1000931   1000969   1000973   1000981   1000999   1001003   1001017   1001023 

   1001027   1001041   1001069   1001081   1001087   1001089   1001093   1001107 

   1001123   1001153   1001159   1001173   1001177   1001191   1001197   1001219
```

The numbers above is what my input looks like and what I need is a simple list of these numbers in integer form so I can do calculations on them. Like I said I am pretty new to Python so I am struggling here.... This isn't homework btw it is for Project Euler, but I wanted some data prearranged for other problems. Also the data is local to the script... no need to read it in from a file.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you already have this as a string:

```
numbers = map(int, s.split())
```

This splits string `s` (which I made up. If you have your own variable name, use that). Because I didn't pass any arguments to `split`, it defaults to spaces. Then `map` runs the `int` function on each element, changing it from a string `"1000003"` to an int `1000003`.

`numbers` is the output, as a list.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your comment. There are never quotes around the element. But when split runs they are still strings (which is why I put quotes). When you map to int, they are numbers. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: yeah I just did I got an EOL error while scanning string literal....thats a text formatting problem ins't it?

Comment: What's your code to get the text into python in the first place. Are you defining it in your .py file? Are you calling input()?

Comment: I just have a list name nums = [..............] with all the data inside the brackets.

Comment: Ok. Put triple quotes around the text. ["""1001 1003 1005"""] etc

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' on the numbers = map(int, nums.split()) code..dang

Comment: Oh sorry, take off the []. So just """1001 1003 1005"""

Comment: I think that is going to do it....idle is "not responding" though...perhaps a reboot or I will do it under unbutu.  I must go but thank you for your time and help!